# C#: Inserting Variable into Text File

Tags: c#, string, text-files

Summary: I want to insert variables into a text file. I tried looking around, so to no avail. Perhaps I'm searching with the wrong key words. I know to insert variables into a string, it's simply:

```
string str1 = "hello {0}";
string str2 = "world";
string final = string.Format(str1, str2); //Output should be "hello world"
```

Following the same notion, I made a text file of str1, loaded the text file into a string variable, and repeated the above process.

str1.txt:

```
hello {0}
```

Code:

```
string str1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\str1.txt"); //Should load the text file as a string
string str2 = "world"
string final = string.Format(str1, str2); //Output should be "hello world"
```

Now, I'm getting the 'Input string was not in a correct format' error when I call string.Format and I'm not too sure why.

Edit: Guess I didn't provide enough information. Sorry! The textfile I'm trying to insert variables into is a textfile of a class with {0}, {1}, ... inserted at various points.

Comment: Debug and check the value of `str1 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code sample on my machine and it works how you expect.  I recommend you look at the content of you str1.txt file and confirm the path resolves properly.  If none of that works, look at the encoding of the file.

Also watch out for stray `{` or `}` characters in your file. Escape them by doubling them up or replace your code with

```
string str1 = "hello {0}";
string str2 = "world";
string final = str1.replace("{0}", str2); //Output should be "hello world"
```

Comment: Hmm interesting..I've done a Console.WriteLine to print the variable and it prints out correctly. The textfile is relatively large though and I need to insert multiple variables. Do you know if multiple lines in the textfile or multiple variables would affect the output?

Comment: multiple lines should be fine.  Just watch out for stray `{` or `}` characters in your file.  Escape them by doubling them up.

Comment: Oh that might be the problem..I'm trying to create a generator for a class. You're saying the brackets for the class functions and variables will mess up the way variables are inserted?

Comment: Yup, that's definitely the problem.  The easiest solution might be to do string.replace("{0}", str2)

Answer (score 0):

`ReadAllText()` is probably giving you a string literal, so `{0}` is actually `\{0\}` and will not function as expected. `string.Format()` is then throws an exception because the first string does not have a valid place to put the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that str1 has a placeholder token in it. Its will need a `{0}` to know where to insert str2 into str1.